# Why am I getting an error on every .get_x()?

Tags: c#, error-handling, syntax-error

I've been trying to find out why I get this error on .get_x(). I have been sitting here for hours trying to find out what's wrong with it but I can't find anything. I'm trying to edit a mod for 'Stardew Valley'. This is the only error left for me to solve. I couldn't post the whole block of code cause it's way too long. Any help is appreciated.

```
using Always_On_Server.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using StardewModdingAPI;
using StardewModdingAPI.Events;
using StardewModdingAPI.Utilities;
using StardewValley;
using StardewValley.Characters;
using StardewValley.Locations;
using StardewValley.Menus;
using StardewValley.Network;
using StardewValley.Objects;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace Always_On_Server
{
  public class ModEntry : Mod
  {
    private ModConfig Config;
    private int gameTicks;
    private int gameClockTicks;
    private int numPlayers;
    private bool IsAutomating;
    public int bedX;
    public int bedY;
    public bool clientPaused;
    private string lastInviteCode;
    private bool debug;
    private bool shippingMenuActive;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, int> PreviousFriendships;
    public int connectionsCount;
    private bool eventCommandUsed;
    private bool eggHuntAvailable;
    private int eggHuntCountDown;
    private bool flowerDanceAvailable;
    private int flowerDanceCountDown;
    private bool luauSoupAvailable;
    private int luauSoupCountDown;
    private bool jellyDanceAvailable;
    private int jellyDanceCountDown;
    private bool grangeDisplayAvailable;
    private int grangeDisplayCountDown;
    private bool goldenPumpkinAvailable;
    private int goldenPumpkinCountDown;
    private bool iceFishingAvailable;
    private int iceFishingCountDown;
    private bool winterFeastAvailable;
    private int winterFeastCountDown;
    private int currentTime;
    private SDate currentDate;
    private SDate eggFestival;
    private SDate dayAfterEggFestival;
    private SDate flowerDance;
    private SDate luau;
    private SDate danceOfJellies;
    private SDate stardewValleyFair;
    private SDate spiritsEve;
    private SDate festivalOfIce;
    private SDate feastOfWinterStar;
    private SDate grampasGhost;
    private int timeOutTicksForReset;
    private int festivalTicksForReset;
    private int shippingMenuTimeoutTicks;
    private SDate currentDateForReset;
    private SDate danceOfJelliesForReset;
    private SDate spiritsEveForReset;

    public override void Entry(IModHelper helper)
    {
      this.Config = (ModConfig) this.get_Helper().ReadConfig<ModConfig>();
      helper.get_ConsoleCommands().Add("server", "Toggles headless 'auto mode' on/off", new Action<string, string[]>(this.ToggleAutoMode));
      helper.get_ConsoleCommands().Add("debug_server", "Turns debug mode on/off, lets server run when no players are connected", new Action<string, string[]>(this.DebugToggle));
      helper.get_Events().get_GameLoop().add_SaveLoaded(new EventHandler<SaveLoadedEventArgs>(this.OnSaveLoaded));
      helper.get_Events().get_GameLoop().add_Saving(new EventHandler<SavingEventArgs>(this.OnSaving));
      helper.get_Events().get_GameLoop().add_OneSecondUpdateTicked(new EventHandler<OneSecondUpdateTickedEventArgs>(this.OnOneSecondUpdateTicked));
      helper.get_Events().get_GameLoop().add_TimeChanged(new EventHandler<TimeChangedEventArgs>(this.OnTimeChanged));
      helper.get_Events().get_GameLoop().add_UpdateTicked(new EventHandler<UpdateTickedEventArgs>(this.OnUpdateTicked));
      helper.get_Events().get_Input().add_ButtonPressed(new EventHandler<ButtonPressedEventArgs>(this.OnButtonPressed));
      helper.get_Events().get_Display().add_Rendered(new EventHandler<RenderedEventArgs>(this.OnRendered));
      helper.get_Events().get_Specialized().add_UnvalidatedUpdateTicked(new EventHandler<UnvalidatedUpdateTickedEventArgs>(this.OnUnvalidatedUpdateTick));
    }
```

Comment: did you forget to add the error to your questions?

Comment: Are you sure that `get_Helper()` is correct, and that you shouldn't just be calling `Helper` (e.g. `this.Helper.ReadConfig<ModConfig>()`)?

Comment: This code is working. I'm just trying to add a couple of things to suit my preferences. It was taken straight out of a mod dll.

Comment: *"It was taken straight out of a mod dll"* -- explain how you did that. Did you use something which looks at a .NET assembly and turns it back into C#? If so, it looks like it did a bad job: it seems to have turned an access of the `Helper` property into the method call `get_Helper()`, and adding an event `SaveLoaded += ...` into the method call `add_SaveLoaded(...)`. So no, you've got a compiled dll which works. I think you've then tried to use a bad tool to turn that back into C#, which produced C# that doesn't work.

Comment: You were right. I used dotPeek to decompile the dll file => C#. Thanks for the help.

Comment: dotPeek's normally quite good: I know for a fact that it can decompile property accesses correctly. Make sure you don't have the option which undoes a lot of compiler transformations enabled.